# Getting r function args from Rcpp c++ function

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have defined a function on the R-side like this:

```
foo <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    ...
}
```

and a function in c++ using Rcpp that gets the global environment and instantiates the R function to execute it from that function. Here is the code:

```
namespace Rcpp;
void myFunction() {
    ...
    Environment env = Environment::global_env();
    Function funct = env["foo"];
    ...
}
```

It works fine, but I would like to check that the R function has exactly 3 args. How can I get the number of args of the R function in the c++ method?

Comment: Why would you interface a function that way from C++?  You still use R, just called in a more cumbersome way.  Did you read our [A Brief Introduction to Rcpp](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) vignette and TAS paper?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Maybe it’s a callback in actual code.

Comment: In the final version of the package, the c++ function will have an argument for the name of the R function to apply, so the user can define multiple R functions and execute them sequentially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [closure access macro `FORMALS`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f5e9878c4fe7453124cef5e56649cef62ef61d77/src/include/Rinternals.h#L482) and the [`PreserveStorage` member function `get__()`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/7f4e64dd92c523d89f3e8a02a891486996845c65/inst/include/Rcpp/storage/PreserveStorage.h#L25) (`Rcpp::Function` is a derived class of `Rcpp::PreserveStorage`) to get the formals, then get its number of elements:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int n_formals() {
    Environment env = Environment::global_env();
    Function funct = env["foo"];
    SEXP sexp_funct = funct.get__();
    SEXP funct_formals = FORMALS(sexp_funct);
    return Rf_length(funct_formals);
}


/*** R
foo <- function(x, y) x + y
n_formals()
foo <- function(x, y, z) x + y + z
n_formals()
*/

# > foo <- function(x, y) x + y
# 
# > n_formals()
# [1] 2
# 
# > foo <- function(x, y, z) x + y + z
# 
# > n_formals()
# [1] 3
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @bra_racing Glad to hear it!