# Validation on a Rcpp::Function object?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

This is a sort of follow up on this question: [Passing R functions to C routines using rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137507/passing-r-functions-to-c-routines-using-rcpp)

I am wondering if I can do validation on Rcpp::Function object, namely number of arguments and type of the returned value?

Here's my code, and I have placed a comment indicating where I'd like to do some checking on the object `Rcpp::Function error_callback`:

```c
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

namespace {
  std::unique_ptr<Rcpp::Function> callback_func_ptr;
}

void wrapper(int error, const char* description)
{
  (*callback_func_ptr)(error, description);
}

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export("glfwSetErrorCallback")]]
void glfw_set_error_callback(Rcpp::Function error_callback) {

  // Is it possible to do some checking on the function error_callback?
  // Such as number of arguments, type, and return type?

  callback_func_ptr = std::make_unique<Rcpp::Function>(error_callback);
  glfwSetErrorCallback((GLFWerrorfun) wrapper);

}
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496292/8416610 help?

Comment: It does indeed.